# Microsoft JScript runtime error when creating android with phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to create an Android project on Windows using Cordova 2.2.0 (PhoneGap). 
But I am getting a message "Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'length' is null or not an object".

Could you please suggest what might be the cause of this error and a possible fix?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this error show when you test your project in an Android emulator or when you test the project in IE?

Comment: @NickRoth No this occurred when I want to create project.

Comment: What are you using to create the project?

Comment: @NickRoth I use this document : http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs in create.js line 38 when trying to find a Android API target.

You need to launch the Android SDK Manager to install a Android API.
You can type android in the command prompt to launch the Android SDK Manager.
Then select a Android API to install the packages.